# Always getting error on passport.js callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a slack login with [passport.js](https://github.com/mjpearson/passport-slack), Sequelize and Node.

But I'm always getting error on returning.
These are my rules:

```
app.get('/auth/slack',
        passport.authorize('slack'));

app.get('/auth/slack/callback', 
        passport.authorize('slack', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
        function(req, res) {
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        }
    );
```

And this is my passport.js:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        console.log("abc deserializeUser");
        User.findById(id).then(function(user){
            done(null, user);
        }).catch(function(e){
            done(e, false);
        });
    });

passport.use('slack', new SlackStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.SLACK_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.SLACK_SECRET,
        callbackURL: process.env.SLACK_REDIRECT,
        scope: "incoming-webhook users:read"
    },
        function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

            var values = { 
                where: { slack_id: profile.id }, 
                defaults: {slack_id: profile.id, name: profile.displayName} 
            };      
            User.findOrCreate(values)
            .spread(function(user, created) {
                return done(user);
            });

        }
    ));
```

I'm always getting this as return

```
[object SequelizeInstance:User]
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`done` callback receives first parameter as an error, second as user, third as flash messages. So you should pass user as second parameter

```
        User.findOrCreate(values)
        .spread(function(user, created) {
            return done(null, user);
        }).catch(function(error){
            return done(error); 
        });
```